# Find the first letter and sign of a sentence with Regex

Tags: regex

Find the first letter and sign of a sentence with Regex.
At the beginning of the sentence can sometimes be letters and sometimes numbers.

```
15. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text
B. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text
C.Lorem ipsum is placeholder text
D .  Lorem ipsum is placeholder text
E,Lorem ipsum is placeholder text
```

**I wrote something like this:**

```
[\dga-zA-Z.]{1\s}
```

[Demo with regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2xMXx4/1)

But it doesn't work right for every sentence. Moreover, it does not detect if there is a space between the first letter/digit and the sign with the sentence.

*Where am I making a mistake?*

---

Also, In terms of performance For such scenarios, it makes more sense to use regex or PHP?

Comment: What does this do --> {1\s} ?

Comment: I wrote an answer that should account for multiple possible conditions mentioned in your qustion, please take a look at it and let me know if you want additional constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will match a single letters **or** multiple digits that are placed at the beginning of a sentence and then followed with either a **single** period or comma:

```
^(([a-zA-Z]{1}|[0-9]+)\s*[.,]{1})(.*)$
```

This is the breakdown:

```
^                  # Asserts position at start of the line
[a-zA-Z]{1}|[0-9]+ # Match a single alphabetic character or one or more digits
\s*                # Matches whitespace characters between 0 and unlimited times
[.,]{1}            # Matches a single period or comma character literal
.*                 # Matches the rest of the text
$                  # Asserts position at end of the line
```

- Group 1 - will return both the letter/numbers and the period/comma (including potential spaces). This is in case you need to get both for some reason.
- Group 2 - will return only letter or numbers at the start of the sentence, which I assume you'll actually be looking for most of the times.
- Group 3 - will return the rest of the text.

The regex will need to be modified depending on what you want. For example if you don't want a match when there are spaces after the letter/digits at the start of the sentence or if you want to include more delimiting characters that mark the separator character. Let me know if you have any additional constraints you'd like this regex conform to.

See the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/swgnqF/5)

Comment: Hi, thank you but I don't see any output in the substitution panel in the demo. I wonder if I'm wrong?

Comment: @J.Doe3 I've updated the answer to include an additional group for the rest of your text. Now you should see the substitution panel in the demo and if not just open it and enter `$3` to get **only** your text.

Answer (score 1):

Hello this matched all of your provided examples

```
([A-Za-z\d ]+)(\.|,)
```

What this does is the following:

- it matches all small, big letters, digits or space. It should find at least
  one of those or more (the + sign).
- It should end with a dot or comma. (\.) Note: In regex, the dot should be escaped.

If that doesn't do the trick, comment below

Edit: demo here: [click](https://regex101.com/r/WtAYVa/4)

Comment: Yes, working but unfortunately, the last example did not work. What could be the reason?

Comment: I thought, the last one shouldn't work. Edited, check this out: https://regex101.com/r/WtAYVa/4      Or:  ([A-Za-z\d ]+)(\.|,)

Comment: Thank you for invested time and effort into answering it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:  `^[\da-zA-Z]+\h*[.,]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2xMXx4/3)

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  [\da-zA-Z]+       # 1 or more letter or digit
  \h*               # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  [.,]              # a dot or a comma
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what OP is looking for as it will match both `AA2C.` and `15A.` and I think he wants it to match only if there is a single character **or** digits at the start of the sentence, not combinations.

Comment: @Matthew: This is your opinion, it is not said in the question.

Comment: Hm, well these parts of my comment should have given away that it's an opinion and not a fact: *"I don't believe..."* and *"I think..."*

Comment: Thank you for invested time and effort into answering it. @Toto